# What does the identity operator look like in QFT, written in momentum eigenstates?

Tags: quantum-field-theory

This is a followup to a question I read recently: [What does the identity operator look like in Quantum Field Theory?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/383467/what-does-the-identity-operator-look-like-in-quantum-field-theory?rq=1)

Out of curiosity, I was writing down what I figured to be the momentum basis vectors in QFT, ignoring for now internal degrees of freedom (spin etc). If each momentum label signifies an additional particle, and $|\Omega\rangle$ is the vacuum state, I wrote:

$$|\Omega\rangle, |p_1\rangle, |p_1 p_2\rangle, |p_1 p_2 p_3\rangle...$$

where actually each of the items in this list contains "infinitely more" than the last, because there is one basis vector for each value of momentum in $\mathbb{R}^3$. I also assumed all states had been normalized.

My question is: How does one write the identity down, in this basis? My guess is:

$$1 = |\Omega\rangle\langle\Omega| +\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|p_1\rangle\langle p_1|d^3p + \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|p_1 p_2\rangle\langle p_1 p_2 |d^3p_1 d^3p_2 \,+\, ...$$

however the lack of integration on the vacuum, and varying numbers of integrals seem a bit unusual to me. Maybe I have misunderstood something fundamental.

Comment: possible duplicate: [How to derive completeness relation in quantum field theory with a Lorentz invariant measure?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/295131/84967).

Comment: Yep, that does answer my question, thank you! So the completeness relation as written is correct! I searched and didn't see that post. It's a different question overall but the answer is included.

Comment: Revisiting this question, I no longer understand how (or even if) the expansion works in the interacting theory. For the free theory I mostly have no questions. But the momentum eigenstates are defined using $a, a^{\dagger}$, which come from the free theory. What guarantee do we have that these states span the whole space in the _interacting_ theory, or even that they lie in the same hilbert space as the interacting theory does?